# Is there anything wrong with my Euler's method equations for a pendulum outside of small angles?

Tags: integration, calculus, approximations

I'm trying to write a program to calculate the angle, angular speed and energy of a pendulum at different times using Euler's method. The equation I started with was:$${\rm d}^2θ/{\rm d}t^2 = - g\sin(θ)/l$$
Is it correct to say that:$${\rm d}θ/{\rm d}t = - gt\sin(θ)/l$$
And therefore:$$θ(t + {\rm d}t) = θ(t) - {\rm d}t*gt\sin(θ)/l$$
?

Comment: No, you went wrong at your first step in going from your first equation to your second. You can only do what you did there if $g Sin(\theta)/l$ were a constant, which of course it isn't.

Comment: I see, thank you. How does *θ* vary then? It must have a *sin(θ)* or *cos(θ)* term because it oscillates from positive to negative, right?

Comment: If you can not make the small angle approximation, the ODE becomes non-linear because of that $\sin\theta$ term. Then the equation becomes quite difficult to solve. You might have to solve it numerically...according to wolfram the analytic solution involves a Jacobi amplitude function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your 2nd order equation $$\ddot{\theta} = -\frac{g}{\ell} \sin \theta $$ is expanded into two first order equations

$$ \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t} \pmatrix{ \theta \\ \omega } = \pmatrix{ \omega \\ -\frac{g}{\ell} \sin \theta} $$

So your Euler step is

$$\pmatrix{ \theta \\ \omega }_{i+1} = \pmatrix{ \theta \\ \omega }_{i} + h \pmatrix{ \omega \\ -\frac{g}{\ell} \sin \theta}_i $$

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I just figured it out but this confirms that my answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I figured it out with the help of one of my uni's webpages. It's $$ω(t + {\rm d}t) = ω(t) - {\rm d}t*g\sin(θ(t)) / l$$$$θ(t + {\rm d}t) = θ(t) + {\rm d}t*ω(t + {\rm d}t)$$using the Euler-Cromer method.

Comment: As a side note, to indicate trig functions in math, use `\sin` instead `sin`. The difference is obvious $\sin(x)$ vs. $sin(x)$. And for `d` in the differential operator, use `{\rm d}` which renders like ${\rm d}x$ vs. $dx$.